# Dense Rank with Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

When the **Amount** is greater than `120` and `Stage =W`, I want to rank based on the **Amount** and **date**.
In the Screenshot **"first_120"** column is showing the correct ranking but starting from 3 as the first two rows have 120 and it doesn't meet the criteria. **Is there a way to start the ranking from 1 instead of 3?**

[image]

I am using the below **calculation**

```sql
case when Amount>120 and stage='W' then
dense_rank() over(partition by stage,owner order by Amount,date)  end as first_120
```

Comment: can you share your full query?

Comment: Use: `case when ARR>120 and stage='W' then dense_rank() over(partition by stage,owner,(ARR>120) order by Amount,date) end as first_120`

Comment: please provide sample data (input and expected output) in a text format so we can use it to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your case statement to the partition by as well.

```sql
CASE WHEN amount > 120 AND stage = 'W' 
AND owner = 12345 
THEN  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY stage, owner, CASE WHEN amount > 120 
AND stage = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ORDER BY Amount, date) END AS First_120
```

[image]